# Phonegap form submit to external page

Tags: forms, redirect, cordova, submit

I am stranded on this one and it is a go-no go issue for our project, so I hope someone can shed some light on the matter.

We are using Phonegap for our mobile app, and are trying to post some data to an external website that we want the users to be redirected to. The user will then see this information filled in inside the website he/she arrives on. 
In a normal html approach we can use a form and have the action url point to the external address. That way the user is redirected and the form data is posted at the same time.

In our Phonegap mobile app however, a form submit does not open the native browser. The user will be redirected to the website and the data is posted but there is no way to move back to the app. The cache has to be cleared before the app is shown again when opening. This is off course not what we want.

When we perform a post ourselves we can send the data but the user is not redirected.

And when we perform a window.open('http://www.externalurl.nl', '_system'); the user gets redirected but we can only pass the data through the query parameterstring of the http get request.

With Phonegap, is there a way to

- post data
- and at the same time redirect the user
- to an external website
- inside the native browser?

Many thanks!

Comment: any luck? looking for something similar